# $a_n:=e^{2\pi i/n} $ , then how to show that $[\mathbb Q(a_n):\mathbb Q(a_n +1/a_n)]=2$ ?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

Let $a_n:=e^{2\pi i/n} $ , then how to show that $[\mathbb Q(a_n):\mathbb Q(a_n +1/a_n)]=2$ ? From this and using Galois theory can we determine which $a_n$ are irrational ?

Comment: Hint: There is a quadratic equation connecting $X, 1/X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$p(x) = x^2 - (a_n + \frac 1 {a_n})x + 1$

Comment: Thanks . And can we say from this and Galois theory , which $a_n$ are irrational ?

Comment: If $a_n$ was rational the extension would be trivial. Once you prove $p(x)$ is irreducible you prove the irrationality of $a_n \forall n$ immediately.